# "The requested URL /drupal/ was not found on this server"

Tags: installation

I know this error has been discussed in other topics, but I think every case is quite specific to what happened before.

I'm new to Wamp and Drupal, and I wanted to install Drupal on my wampserver. I followed this tutorial first - https://www.drupal.org/node/114493 
It told me to go to localhost/drupal and perform the installation.
Drupal was installed, and I came to step 7: site configuration. 
Because it wouldn't work with a random site name, I realized this tutorial had some steps missing, so I didn't fill in the site configuration.

So I started following this tutorial - https://www.drupal.org/node/1995312. This told me to  create a folder for my site in the www folder: I choose Kristientestdrupal.com.
The database and the settingsfile were already created in a different way, by the previous tutorial. 
Now Kristientestdrupal.com was visible on localhost. The tutorial told me that if i clicked it I would go to the drupal installation (which I allready performed, but okay, I thought I could go to Drupal site configuration). I clicked it and I got the message that the site was not reachable.

So I retried the link localhost/drupal. This gave me a blank page (404 Not Found) with the message:

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /drupal/ was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at localhost Port 80

It's clearly not working because I did not configure the site yet? But how can I get back to the page for site configuration?